# If the sum of two irreducible fractions is an integer, then the denominators are equal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions

I have to show the following:"If the sum of two irreducible fractions with positive denominators is an integer, then the denominators are equal." $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=k, \text{ where k an integer }$$
Since the fractions are irreducible, $(a,b)=1$ and $(c,d)=1$. Right?
But how can I continue??

Comment: $ad+bc=kbd$, what does it say about divisibility of $d$ by $b$ and $b$ by $d$?

Comment: "Fractions" can be tricky in number-theoretic reasoning. So an almost automatic first step is to get rid of them, in this case by multiplying through by $bd$.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś  André Nicolas Could you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation means $ad+bc=bd k$. It follows that $b$ divides $ad$, hence also $d$. The rest is for you ...

Comment: you must mean $ad+bc=bdk$ :-)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Could you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=k \text{ with } (a,b)=1, (c,d)=1$$
$$\Rightarrow ad+bc=kbd$$
$$>ad=kbd-cb \Rightarrow ad=b(kd-c) \Rightarrow b|ad \xrightarrow{(a,b)=1} b|d (1)$$
$$>cb=kbd-ad \Rightarrow cb=d(kb-a) \Rightarrow d|cb \xrightarrow{(c,d)=1} d|b (2)$$
$$(1) \Rightarrow b \leq d$$
$$(2) \Rightarrow d \leq b$$
So $b=d$.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.

Comment: Ok!Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Bezout's Identity says that since $(a,b)=1$
$$
ax+by=1\tag{1}
$$
and that since $(c,d)=1$
$$
cu+dv=1\tag{2}
$$
Multiplying your equation by $bd$ gives
$$
ad+bc=bdk\tag{3}
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $d$ to get
$$
\color{#C00000}{adx}+bdy=d\tag{4}
$$
Multiply $(3)$ by $x$ to get
$$
\color{#C00000}{adx}+bcx=bdkx\tag{5}
$$
Solving $(5)$ for $adx$ and plugging that into $(4)$ yields
$$
d=b(dy+dkx-cx)\tag{6}
$$
Multiply $(2)$ by $b$ to get
$$
\color{#C00000}{bcu}+bdv=b\tag{7}
$$
Multiply $(3)$ by $u$ to get
$$
adu+\color{#C00000}{bcu}=bdku\tag{8}
$$
Solving $(8)$ for $bcu$ and plugging that into $(7)$ yields
$$
b=d(bku-au+bv)\tag{9}
$$
Equations $(6)$ and $(9)$ should finish things off.

Comment: Ok!Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: It is along the same lines as the others, but I think of Bezout as a low level idea.