# Are there integer solutions to $a^2 + (\frac{c}{d})^2= (\frac{e}{f})^2$ with $\gcd(c,d)=1=\gcd(e,f)$, $f\neq 1\neq d$, $f\neq d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there integers $a,c,d,e,f$ such that $$a^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{d}\right)^2= \left(\dfrac{e}{f}\right)^2,\quad\gcd(c,d)=1=\gcd(e,f),\quad f\neq 1\neq d, ~~~ f\neq d $$ As for a contradiction we would have $$a^2 = \left(\dfrac{e}{f}-\dfrac{c}{d}\right) \left(\dfrac{e}{f}+\dfrac{c}{d}\right)  =  \left(\dfrac{ed-cf}{fd}\right)\left(\dfrac{ed+cf}{fd}\right).$$ Thus $(fd)^2\mid\biggl((ed-cf)(ed+cf)\biggr)$ which happens if $fd\mid (ed-cf)$ or $fd\mid (ed+cf)$. We know $fd$ cannot divide $ed$ because $$fd\cdot k = ed \Rightarrow  f \cdot k = e\Rightarrow k = \dfrac{e}{f} \Rightarrow \gcd(e,f)>1$$ But if $fd$ cant divide $ed$ does that mean $fd$ cannot divide the sum or difference $ed+cf$ or $ed-cf$. Instantly, we should say $a^2$ is not an integer which is a contradiction.

Comment: Please don't try to micromanage spacing in title lines. The website uses responsive design to help it be readable across multiple screen formats, but micromanaging spacing within formulas by adding unbreakable spaces hobbles it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry about that

Comment: @peterwhy yes sorry that is not allowed

Comment: $1^2+\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^2=\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)^2$.

Comment: Do you allow $f=d \ne 1$?  Maybe $$1^2 + \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^2$$

Comment: In your reasoning what if $ed+cf$ is a multiple of $f^2d^2$ for instance ? You separated the two terms as if they needed to be both integers, but it is possible that one rational factor compensates for the other.

Comment: @GEdgar I think about restricting $a\neq 1$ because im searching for semi congruent numbers and as a consequence the number $n= 1/2 a \dfrac{c}{d}$ would be congruent number so we need $d\vert a$ or $a\neq 1$

Comment: For $a\ne 1$, maybe $$2^2 + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Restriction $a \ne 1$ by itself does not help. $$5^2 + \left(\frac{20}{3}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{25}{3}\right)^2$$

Comment: @peterwhy what about $f\neq d$ . Must we have $f=d$ for any solution?

Comment: @GEdgar what about $f\neq d$?

Comment: @zwim oh I see yea that was mistake I guess

Comment: No, $f=d$ must hold.

Comment: @GEdgar Why though here do we need $fd \vert cf $?

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151469/242) in the linked dupe, since the reduced fractions $\,e^2/f^2, \ -c^2/d^2\,$ sum to an integer they have equal denominators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.  Suppose $f \ne d$ and $f \ne -d$.  Say $f$ does not divide $d$.  From
$$
a^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{d}\right)^2= \left(\dfrac{e}{f}\right)^2
$$
we get
$$
(ad)^2 + c^2= \left(\dfrac{ed}{f}\right)^2
$$
an integer equal to a non-integer.  Similarly for the case $d$ does not divide $f$.

Comment: We didn't restrict $\gcd(f,d) =1$.

Comment: Correct, you did not, and neither did I.  Is this not right:  if $gcd(f,e)=1$ and $f|ed$, then $f|d$ ?

Comment: I see its because it can't divide $e$ yea its not possible.

Comment: the logic doesn't seem right we just found that f must divide d we didnt show there is not a solution

Comment: we cant try to write $d = fk$ for some $k$.

Comment: @Life_is_pie As you stated, since the answer shows $f\mid d$, then $d = fk$ for some integer $k$. The answer also proves that $d\mid f$, so $f=dm$ for some integer $m$. Combining the $2$ equations gives, since $d\neq 0$, that $d = (dm)k = dmk \;\to\; 1 = mk$. Thus, $m = k = \pm 1$, meaning we need to have $f=\pm d$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan okay that makes since. You can multiply by $d^2$ or $f^2$

Comment: @GEdgar I will accept you answer because you were aware of both equations even though you wrote one and the solution is derived from your idea.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the trivial equations $0^2 + 0^2 = 0^2$ , $y^2 + 0 = y^2$ and $0^2 + x^2 = x^2$, we have that $a,c,d,e,f \neq 0$.

So we want to solve

$$ a^2 + (c/d)^2  = (e/f)^2 $$

by multiplying both sides by $d^2$ or by $f^2$ we arrive at the two equations :

$$ (ad)^2 + c^2 = (ed/f)^2 $$

and

$$(af)^2 + (cf/d)^2 = e^2$$

We must conclude that since $\gcd(e,f) = 1$ in the first equation and the LHS is an integer , we get that $f|d$.
Likewise for the second equation by $\gcd(c,d)=1$ we get that $d|f$.

However if $f|d$ and $d|f$ and $f,d$ are nonzero, we get either $f=g$ or a contradiction.

But you wanted $f \neq d$ so your equation has no nontrivial solution.

Comment: your proof is more accurate (complete) but it was derived from GEdgar answer.

Comment: @Life_is_pie I did not even read his answer until 5 min ago. I do not need help with trivial number theory. Avoiding divisibility in easy number theory is almost impossible, unless you want an unnessary long or complicated proof.  I guess I am a bit offended by " derived ' and you just wanted a reason/motivation to accept his answer instead of mine.  That's ok, you can accept his answer. He was first and correct, so its ok.

Comment: I would also like to modify question and look for solutions when $d\vert a$. I will ask this is next question because as a consequence the number $n = 1/2 a \dfrac{c}{d}$ would be congruent. For this to happen we need to look for solutions when $d\vert a$.

Comment: As for your variant of the question, that can be resolved in a similar way.

Comment: I would like to add that when I answered you did not accept any answers, so I felt a more clear answer was needed.

Comment: at the time I was still gathering my thoughts on why his is correct. It's because he said "similarly" which indicates he was aware of both equations even though he didn't write it. Which would lead us to the same conclusion

Comment: I prefer my own answer ;) But ok :) @Life_is_pie

Comment: I do as well as I said yours is more accurate but It is more appropriate to give him the points. I just posted next question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832727/are-there-any-semi-congruent-numbers

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).