# Does each proper congruent number correspond to some Pythagorean triple?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Define a proper congruent number as an integer which represents the area of some right triangle $\triangle ABC$ whose legs are both strictly in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. For every proper congruent number there exist $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$ such that

\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{d}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{e}{f}\right)^2,
\end{equation}

with $d\mid a $ and $b\mid c$. Is it true that $f = bd$ and $e^2 = (ad)^2+(bc)^2$? If so we see that each proper congruent number corresponds to some Pythagorean triple that has non square free components.

Comment: Do you also want $ac/(2bd)$ to be an integer?

Comment: This is your 3rd question about pythagorean triples today, and all very similar. You got helpful answers. I suggest you try this one yourself. Show some effort in your question or give an answer.

Comment: @mick there you go

Comment: Why edit the MathJax into an identical looking expression?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash If you are asking about my edit, it *doesn't* look identically the same.  $\bigtriangleup ABC$ is not the same as $\triangle ABC$, and $a\vert b$ is not the same as $a \mid b$.  In both cases, the spacing in the former is not quite correct, and the spacing in the latter is better.

Comment: Note $\,b\mid c,\ (c,d)=1\Rightarrow (b,d)=1,$ so $\,(b^2,d^2)=1\,$ so the denominator of the sum $ = {\rm lcm}(b^2,d^2)=b^2d^2\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194978/242), so the denoms are equal $\,f^2 = b^2d^2\,$ by [unique fractionization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque I dont think we need unique factorization just show both sides are in lowest terms

Comment: @BillDubuque if you have two fractions in $\mathbb{Q}$ that are in lowest terms then we can show that there sum of squares are also in lowest terms. So reduces rational numbers are closed under this operation.

Comment: Euclid's Lemma, gcd laws, etc are all equivalent to uniqueness of prime factorizations. Uniqueness of reduced fractions easily follows from such (and is *equivalent* to unique factorization). Using uniqueness of reduced fractions is usually the easiest way to prove results like this (e.g. said one-line proof here).

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks so it does mean that each proper congruent number corresponds to some primitive triple  $(a,b,c)$ right? We should actually go backwards and say if $e^2 = (ad)^2+(bc)^2$ for some integers then $n= 1/2\dfrac{ac}{bd}$ is a proper congruent.

Comment: That the least denom of the sum of two reduced fractions *with coprime denoms* is the product of their denoms (cf. my prior comment) is proved here in many places, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3208796/242) in the 2nd linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks that will shorten what I need. If $(ad ,bc,e) $ is a primitive triple with $a\vert d$ and $b\vert c$ then $n=1/2\dfrac{ad}{bc}$ is a congruent number when $ad$ containts more factors of 2 then $bc$. Similarly, if $n$ is a proper congruent then $e^2 = (ad)^2 + (bc)^2$ with $a\vert d$ and $b\vert c$ . So there seem to be mapping from each primitve Pythagorean triple to each congruent number.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n$ is a proper congruent number with $1=\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,b)=\gcd(e,f)$. Since $n$ is congruent it represents the area of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ which has area $n=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a}{b})(\frac{c}{d})  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{ac}{bd}$. Since $n$ is an integer it must follow that $bd\vert ac$. Since $n$ is proper we know that $b$ must divide $c$ and $d$ must divide $a$. Let $i$ denote the largest power of $b$ so that $b^{i}\vert c$ but $b^{i+1} \not \vert c$. Similarly, let $j$ denote the largest power of $d$ so that $d^{j}\vert a$ but $d^{j+1} \not \vert a$. Write $a =d^{j}q_2$ and $c =b^iq_1$ for some quotients $q_1$ and $q_2$, then by the hypothesis it follows that

\begin{equation}
\label{Equation 1}
\begin{split}
(\frac{a}{b})^2+(\frac{c}{d})^2 & =(\frac{e}{f})^2\\
& \Downarrow\\
(\frac{d^{j}q_2}{b})^2+(\frac{b^iq_1}{d})^2 & =(\frac{e}{f})^2\\
& \Downarrow\\
\frac{d^{2j}q_2^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^{2i}q_1^2}{d^2} & =\frac{e^2}{f^2}\\
& \Downarrow\\
\frac{d^{2j+1}q_2^2+ b^{2i+1}q_1^2}{b^2d^2} & =\frac{e^2}{f^2}\\
\end{split}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now suppose that the numerator and the denominator of the last equality in Eq.(1) are not in lowest terms. Then it must follow that $$b^2d^2\vert \left(d^{2j+1}q_2^2+ b^{2i+1}q_1^2\right)$$ but $bd\vert b^2d^2$ so then $$bd\vert b^2d^2\vert  \left(d^{2j+1}q_2^2+ b^{2i+1}q_1^2\right).$$ Thus the product $bd$ divides the numerator. This implies $b$ and $d$ divide the numerator individually, but this cannot happen because $b$ divides the numerator if and only if $b\vert q_2^2$ (as $\gcd(b,d) = 1$ as $d$ is a divisor of $a$), but $a=d^jq_2$ and $1=\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,d^jq_2)$, which means $b$ cannot divides $q_2$. The same type of argument holds for the integer $d$. Thus the numerator and the denominator are in lowest terms, which implies that is $f^2 = b^2d^2 = (bd)^2$. Hence, $f=bd$ as desired.

Comment: You can simplify the argument to "A perfect square rational that is also an integer, is a perfect square integer".

Comment: @CalvinLin sorry it does seem slightly long like this but shows each integer