# Is it possible for two simplified non integer fractions to have an integer sum and an integer product?

Tags: fractions

Is it possible for two simplified non integer fractions to have an integer sum and an integer product?

Let’s say the fractions are $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$. For them to multiply to an integer, $d$ must divide $a$ and $b$ must divide $c$. We can express $a$ as $kd$ and $c$ as $mb$ for some integers $m$ and $k$. Their sum is $\dfrac{kd}{b} + \dfrac{mb}{d}$, which simplifies to $\dfrac{kd^2+mb^2}{bd}$. I don’t know how to proceed from here to find if this can ever be an integer. I checked what would happen if $b=d$, but that would mean that the fractions are integers.

Comment: Hint:  use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687824/if-the-sum-of-two-irreducible-fractions-is-an-integer-then-the-denominators-are)

Comment: @lulu ohh ok ty

Comment: You can post your complete answer below, as a solution to your own problem.  That way people here can check your work and the site can consider the question resolved.  I think that the question I linked to really is all you needed to complete the logic you were following.